# 404 error : no comment matches the given query

Tags: django

I've searched enough about this problem, but haven't been able to find a solution.

Please help me.

The board detail view and comment template containing the comment list were all imported.
I brought it in as much detail as possible, so I hope you give me a way.

View.py

```
class comment_delete(DeleteView):
model = Comment
success_url = reverse_lazy('board_list.html')


class board_detail(generic.DetailView):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    rsDetail = Board.objects.filter(b_no=pk)

    rsData = Board.objects.get(b_no=pk)
    rsData.b_count += 1
    rsData.save()
    
    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(Board_id=pk).order_by('-id')

    return render(request, "board_detail.html", {
        'rsDetail': rsDetail,
        'comment_list' : comment_list
    })
    
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    bno = get_object_or_404(Board, b_no=self.kwargs['pk'])
    cnote = request.POST.get('c_note')
    cwriter = request.POST.get('c_writer')
    
    rows = Comment.objects.create(
        Board   = bno,
        c_note  = cnote,
        c_writer    = cwriter
    )

    return redirect(reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk']}))
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.home, name="home"),
path('board/', views.board.as_view(), name="board"),
path('board/<int:pk>/', views.board_detail.as_view(), name="board_detail"),
path('board_write/', views.board_write, name="board_write"),
path('board_insert', views.board_insert.as_view(), name="board_insert"),
path('board_edit/', views.board_edit, name="board_edit"),
path('board_update/', views.board_update, name="board_update"),
path('board_delete/', views.board_delete, name="board_delete"),

path('board/comment/update/', views.comment_update, name="comment_update"),
path('board/comment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.comment_delete.as_view(), name="comment_delete")
```

comment.html

```
{% if not comment_list %}
<p class="text-center"> empty </p>
{% endif %}

<div style="margin:20px 0; margin-right:400px; margin-left:400px;">
{% for i in comment_list %}
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:#f1eee3;height:45px;border-top: 1px solid #333;">
            <td style="padding-left: 10px;border-top: 1px solid #eee;width: 114px;" align="center" width="20%">{{ i.c_writer }}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 0;" align="left" width="70%">{{ i.c_note }}
                <span style="color: #999;font-size: 11px;display: block;">{{ i.c_date }}</span>
            </td>
            {% if user.username == i.b_writer or user.is_staff %}
            <form action="{% url 'comment_update' %}">
                <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 0;" align="right" width="10%">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">edit</button>
                </td>
            </form>
            <form action="{% url 'comment_delete' pk=i.Board_id %}" method='POST'>
            {% comment %} <form action="{% url 'comment_delete' Board_id=i.Board_id id=i.id %}" method='POST'> {% endcomment %}
            {% csrf_token %}
                <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top: 1px solid #eee;padding: 10px 0;padding-right: 5px;" align="right" width="10%">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" style="margin-right:10px;">delete</button>
                </td>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

{% include 'comment_write.html' %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise the delete view except only the pk from the object you want to delete so in your case that would be the comment :

```
path('board/comment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.comment_delete.as_view(), name="comment_delete")
```

Also you were not using the comment ID but the board ID, which of course is different and will cause your url to point the incorrect object.

The same logic applies to the **DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView**, those views expects the primary key (or ID) that you reference in the **model attribute** within those views.

Last thing, what is `i.Board_id` and `id.id` ? When using variable be the most explicit, do name your variables in lower case as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly, I don't understand you very well because I'm still a beginner.

So I modified it like the body with the code you wrote down, but the same error occurred.

Comment: No problem, your view (DeleteView) requires only the primary key of your object your want to delete, in your case the comment.
In your path just provide the PK of the object for the comment, could you share the snippet of code in your template ?

Comment: @ᄋᄉaᄋ one thing you could try to see if your url works is to access the page with a PK you know exist, create comment from your admin and check the primary key object either in the URL or from the table.

Comment: It's too hard. I brought it because I thought you were asking me to show you the team plate. I brought a view with comment_list, so please check it out.

Comment: replace `{% url 'comment_delete' Board_id=i.Board_id id=i.id %}` with `{% url 'comment_delete' i.id %}`

Comment: It's solved. THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH.
I'm going to make an UpdateView, so I can do it the same way, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer, read carefully so you understand the basic principles of those views, but in short yes this is similar. 
Once you understand do not forget to mark the answer as solved so other people  can be help in the future

Comment: i accepted answer. thank you

Comment: Can you check 70381393 too?